# Slow inserts with bq + Backend Error

Tags: google-bigquery

We are experiencing trouble with inserting our data into BigQuery.
We are located in The Netherlands.

**The command:**
adm@la478 ads_csv $ time bq load --debug_mode --skip_leading_rows 1 --max_bad_records 100 --project_id 197553342340  ad_monitoring.ad ad_bd9a6230-2d34-4cf1-8553-04d9c2f8c52b.csv.gz
BigQuery error in load operation: Backend Error

**The metrics:**
real 4m35.997s
user 0m0.963s
sys 0m0.169s

**The filesize:**
-rw-rw-rw-  1 adm admin  39M Jul 10 17:02 ad_bd9a6230-2d34-4cf1-8553-04d9c2f8c52b.csv.gz
200MB uncompressed

Can you please advice use what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm investigating the issue on our backend, but you may have better luck (especially from europe) if you stage the import through google storage. If you run `gsutil cp ad_monitoring.ad ad_bd9a6230-2d34-4cf1-8553-04d9c2f8c52b.csv.gz gs://your_bucket/ad_monitoring.ad ad_bd9a6230-2d34-4cf1-8553-04d9c2f8c52b.csv.gz`, you can then change the bq command line to:

`bq load --debug_mode --skip_leading_rows 1 --max_bad_records 100 --project_id 197553342340 ad_monitoring.ad gs://your_bucket/ad_bd9a6230-2d34-4cf1-8553-04d9c2f8c52b.csv.gz`

I'm looking for your jobs in our logs, and it looks like there have been a bunch of recent load jobs that failed with 'TOO_MANY_ERRORS'. If you use `bq ls -j` and `bq show -j <job_id>` you can get more information about these.